# Converted to comment

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation, comments, convert-to-comment

Why was [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143019/none-of-the-dvds-can-be-read/146526#comment176583_143019) made into a comment? I thought you needed [50 reputation points](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/comment) to make a comment?

Comment: Because it's not an answer, it's a request for further information from the OP...

Comment: And a moderator deemed it good enough to bend the rules a bit by converting it to a comment rather than simply deleting.