# User was able to leave a comment without having the required privilege

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How could a user with 1 reputation point leave a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107063/how-could-a-user-with-1-reputation-point-leave-a-comment)
>   [Converted to comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134525/converted-to-comment)

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488966/last-line-of-a-paragraph-contains-a-single-word-only) question, a user named [Ben Brooks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1576701/ben-brooks) left a comment with only 1 reputation. Since 50 reputation is required to comment anywhere, how is it possible that this was able to comment?

> [image]

Comment: They may have tried to post that as an answer and it got auto-converted (because it was basically a link). Not sure if that script is supposed to catch the under-comment-rep threshold.

Comment: @animuson would you tell me  than what the meaning of the 50 reputation to comment anywhere ?

Comment: @Mayankswami - see: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The user attempted to post that as an answer, but it was [automatically converted to a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/answer-appears-automatically-converted-as-a-comment/98955#98955) by the system.

There is [some debate](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=1084467#1084467) over whether or not this is something that *should* happen, since as you noted the user cannot leave comments otherwise (he can only write comments with 50 reputation except when the system converts his answers automatically), but it's currently the expected behaviour.

Comment: dont you think its creating the conflict in the privileges

Comment: It might be, so it's possible that it will be changed in the future. The answer will only be converted to a comment in some cases, so it's not something to worry too much about.

Comment: @Mayankswami Sort of, but the rules for automated to-comment conversion are pretty specific. I don't recall the exact details, but the answer has to involve a link to another question on the same site and not much else, if memory serves. There's a trade-off between creating a comment from someone with less than 50 rep and letting a very low quality answer (really, just a pointer to another question - likely a duplicate) go through. A comment is usually more appropriate, so we automatically convert.