# How can a 1 rep user comment?

Tags: bug, reputation, comments, privileges

I came across this question on Stack Overflow: [What is difference between const and non const key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638154/what-is-difference-between-const-and-non-const-key), which has one comment by user [Soerium](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2538009/soerium). I  hovered over his name link and saw that he has just the 1 rep.

In the [privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), *Comment Everywhere* privileges require 50 rep. Soerium is not OP of question.

Comment: You have already asked this question before: [User was able to leave a comment without having the required privilege](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147587/187824).

Comment: .. i just forget it ..:( now it looks i should stop contributing on meta ... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that user has answer a question which was flagged by other users ( as NAA ). While handling the flag moderator has converted his/her answer to the comment ( if it is useful answer ).

Answer (score 2):

If a user (mostly new) posts link only answer then it is [automatically converted to comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98950/187824). This looks the same case.